# join xargs' output by newlines

Tags: bash, xargs

I want to join output of the `xargs` output by new lines. I do this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -n 1 iconv -f UTF-16 | ...other-commands...
```

I take one file at a time and convert it to UTF-8 (the system locale). All of the `*.txt` are one-liners without newline character at the end. So the output of `xargs` is a mess of text.

How do you separate items of `xargs` output by `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ugly solution:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | { xargs -n 1 -I_ bash -c 'iconv -f UTF-16 _;echo '; }| ...other-commands...
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works just fine. `find . -name '*.txt' | {xargs -n 1 -I% bash -c 'iconv -f UTF-16 %; echo;'}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | (xargs -n 1 iconv -f UTF-16; echo; ) | ...other-commands...
```

That should add a newline after the output of xargs, before piping to the other commands.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work like this.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong.  ( created a subshell, { would probably have worked (like the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you could have done:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | parallel -k "iconv -f UTF-16 {}; echo" | ...other-commands...
```

As an added bonus the `iconv`s would run in parallel.

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1